# React native - Rendering none primitives from fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, native, react-native-flatlist

Im new to react native and trying to learn the basics. I want get some data from my backend and present it neatly in a custom object. However I keep getting the same error "Objects are not valid react child... If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. I can get it work using primitives ( etc.), but how do I use custom objects?

I tried using both FlatList and Scrollview without luck.

[This is a link to the picture of the code, not allowed to embed pictures yet :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwDRO.png)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import Gleam from '../Elements/Gleam'

function CurrentGleamScreen() {
  const [gleamData, setGleamData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.17:8080/getActualGleams')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setGleamData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);
  return (
    <View>
      {isLoading ? <Text>Loading...</Text> :
        (
          <ScrollView>
            {gleamData.map(gleam => <Gleam key={gleam.headerText}>{gleam.bodyText}</Gleam>)}
          </ScrollView>
        )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default CurrentGleamScreen
```

Comment: try this `setGlemData[jsonData]`

Comment: Please just copy paste the code into your question. We can't copy your code from a picture to test it, and image links can break making your question useless to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `gleam.bodyText` is not a string, but an object. You can't just jam an object into an html element. You can convert it to a string first if that's what you want.

```
<ScrollView>
  {gleamData.map(gleam => <Gleam key={gleam.headerText}>{JSON.stringify(gleam.bodyText)}</Gleam>)}
</ScrollView>
```